# Excluding items cited in another .tex file from biblatex bibliography?

Tags: biblatex

Suppose I have two .tex files, each of which must have a bibliography. However, I want the bibliography in the second file to contain *only* citations that are not in the first. As an example:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,natbib=true,backend=biber,maxbibnames=99,url=false]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\bibliography{test}

\begin{document}

This is test file 1 \citep{Tversky:Kahneman:1990,Tversky:Kahneman:1974}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This first file cites two sources.

Here is the second file:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,natbib=true,backend=biber,maxbibnames=99,url=false]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\bibliography{test}

\begin{document}

This is test file 2 \citep{Tversky:Kahneman:1990,Kahneman:1973}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Notice that this tex document cites two sources: one that was cited in the first, and one that wasn't. I'd like the reference section here to include *only* `Kahneman:1973`, because `Tversky:Kahneman:1990` is included in the first.

Here's my `test.bib` in case you want to compile the files above...

```
@book{Kahneman:1973,
author = {Kahneman, D.},
title = {Attention and effort},
publisher = {Prentice-Hall},
year = {1973},
address = {Englewood Cliffs, NJ},
confidential = {n}
}

@article{Tversky:Kahneman:1974,
author = {Tversky, A. and Kahneman, D.},
title = {Judgment under Uncertainty: {H}euristics and Biases},
journal = {Science},
year = {1974},
volume = {185},
number = {4157},
pages = {1124-1131},
note = {10.1126/science.185.4157.1124},
confidential = {n}
}

@incollection{Tversky:Kahneman:1990,
author = {Tversky, A. and Kahneman, D.},
title = {Judgements under uncertainty: {H}euristics and Biases},
booktitle = {Rationality in action: {C}ontemporary approaches.},
publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
year = {1990},
pages = {171-188},
editor = {Moser, Paul K.},
address = {New York},
confidential = {n}
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this? I am using `latexmk` to compile my document. I'm also open to ways of using extra scripting to do it. Thanks!

Comment: Are there any news here? Are you still interested in a solution?

Comment: @Johannes_B Are *you* interested in a solution? I have cooked something up below. Maybe it is enough to get this question off the unanswered list.

Answer (score 1):

We can use a similar strategy to [Cite references in the order that they appear in another file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/273596/35864).

Again we import the other document (your first file, in the example `\jobname-ext`) in a savebox wrapped in a `refsegment`.
Now we only have to filter out those entries from that segment and discard them, that is done with the `onlynew` filter just like in [Multiple reference lists using biblatex: how to remove duplicated entries?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/245971/35864).

The second file (in the example `\jobname`) will then have the following document environment

```
\begin{document}
\importcites{\jobname-ext}
This is test file 2 \cite{sigfridsson,worman}

\printbibliography[filter=onlynew]
\end{document}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[british]{scrartcl}  
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber,sorting=none,backref=true,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage{docmute}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-ext.tex}
\documentclass[british]{scrartcl}  
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
This is test file 1 \cite{sigfridsson,geer}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\makeatletter
\defbibenvironment{plainimport}{}{}{}
\newsavebox{\importbox}
\newcommand{\importcites}[1]{%
  \sbox\importbox{\vbox{%
    \citetrackerfalse
    \begin{refsegment}
      \defbibfilter{onlynew}{not segment=\therefsegment}
      \input{#1}
      \let\blx@anchor\@empty
      \printbibliography[env=plainimport,segment=\therefsegment]
    \end{refsegment}}}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\importcites{\jobname-ext}
This is test file 2 \cite{sigfridsson,worman}

\printbibliography[filter=onlynew]
\end{document}
```

[image: example output of the second file]

Comment: One solution is better than none :-)

Comment: Credits go to PLK for telling me how to use `\defbibfilter` more effectively ([here](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/344)).