# Multiple reference lists using biblatex: how to remove duplicated entries?

Tags: biblatex, biber, subdividing

I'd like to have two lists of references in my document.  However, I want each reference to appear only once in the entire document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{foo}
\begin{document}
\begin{refsection}

\section{Previous Track Record}
I am an acknowledged authority on aardvarks \cite{mynature}.
\printbibliography[prefixnumbers=A,heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}

\section{Research}

\begin{refsection}
I will use the methods developed in \cite{mynature} to address
the questions raised in \cite{other}.
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}    
\end{document}
```

Here are the contents of foo.bib:

```
@article{mynature,
author={Ego Sum},
journal={Nature Soundbites},
title={Aardvarks are artistic},
year={2013}
}

@article{other,
author={Tu Es},
journal={Gnu Letters},
title={Gnus gnaw gnomes},
year={2014}
}
```

In the two bibliographies, I only want the paper in *Nature Soundbites* to appear once, and be cited in both places as [A1].

Any suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use `refsection` here, because the contents of `refsections` are kept completely separate and independent of each other, "synchronising" labels between them is therefore not possible.

Here we can use `refsegment`s instead, they are not kept local, but work together.

A `\printbibliography` does not automatically restrict itself to the current `refsegment`, it needs to be told to do so with `segment=\therefsegment`, for example. Your first section then looks like this

```
\begin{refsegment}
\defbibfilter{notother}{not segment=\therefsegment}
\section{Previous Track Record}
I am an acknowledged authority on aardvarks \cite{sigfridsson}.
\printbibliography[prefixnumbers=A,heading=subbibliography,segment=\therefsegment]
\end{refsegment}
```

For the second section, we want to ignore those entries from the other segment, this can be done via a filter

```
\defbibfilter{notother}{not segment=\therefsegment}
```

issued in the first segment.

Then the second section becomes

```
\begin{refsegment}
\section{Research}
I will use the methods developed in \cite{sigfridsson} to address
the questions raised in \cite{geer}.
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,segment=\therefsegment,filter=notother]
\end{refsegment}
```

Or use `\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, filter=notother]` which only ignores the entries from segment one (and does not additionally restrict itself to the current segment - with your set-up there is no difference, but with a bigger document there could be).

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{refsegment}
\defbibfilter{notother}{not segment=\therefsegment}
\section{Previous Track Record}
I am an acknowledged authority on aardvarks \cite{sigfridsson}.
\printbibliography[prefixnumbers=A,heading=subbibliography,segment=\therefsegment]
\end{refsegment}

\begin{refsegment}
\section{Research}
I will use the methods developed in \cite{sigfridsson} to address
the questions raised in \cite{geer}.
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,segment=\therefsegment,filter=notother]
\end{refsegment}    
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

You can let the numbering in the second list start anew by adding `resetnumbers=true` to the `\printbibliography` call.

---

Another solution that does not require you to know the number of the segment in advance uses bibliography categories and a modification of `\AtEveryCitekey` that is kept local.

```
\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd*{\AtEveryCitekeyLocal}{\appto\blx@hook@citekey}
\makeatother
```

and

```
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{firstsection}
```

Then we use `\AtEveryCitekeyLocal{\addtocategory{firstsection}{\thefield{entrykey}}}` from within the first segment. This assignment is kept local such that only citations within this group (i.e. within this refsegment) get added to the category.

```
\begin{refsegment}
\section{Previous Track Record}
\AtEveryCitekeyLocal{\addtocategory{firstsection}{\thefield{entrykey}}}
I am an acknowledged authority on aardvarks \cite{sigfridsson}.
\printbibliography[prefixnumbers=A,heading=subbibliography,segment=\therefsegment]
\end{refsegment}
```

The second segment bibliography simply needs to filter those works with `notcategory=firstsection`

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{firstsection}
\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd*{\AtEveryCitekeyLocal}{\appto\blx@hook@citekey}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{refsegment}
\section{Previous Track Record}
\AtEveryCitekeyLocal{\addtocategory{firstsection}{\thefield{entrykey}}}
I am an acknowledged authority on aardvarks \cite{sigfridsson}.
\printbibliography[prefixnumbers=A,heading=subbibliography,segment=\therefsegment]
\end{refsegment}

\begin{refsegment}
\section{Research}
I will use the methods developed in \cite{sigfridsson} to address
the questions raised in \cite{geer}.
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,segment=\therefsegment,notcategory=firstsection]
\end{refsegment}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Credits go to PLK for telling me how to use `\defbibfilter` more effectively ([here](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/344)).