# Printing bibliography in another document

Tags: bibliographies

Let's say that I have two documents. Is it possible to print the references from citation of the first file into the second one? (something like this) 
1) Presentation:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[backen=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{document}

lipsum \textcite{something}

\end{document}
```

2) Article

```
  \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[backen=biber]{biblatex}

    \begin{document}

    \printbibliography

    \end{document}
```

What I want to achieve is to generate a document with the reference of {something}

Comment: In general this is not possible with `biblatex`, but there are workarounds for specific situations if you are willing to put in some manual work: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/426964/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/273596/35864

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just copy the .bbl file which was created with the first document (compile tex and run biber) and rename it for the second document. Then compile the second document without rerunning biber.

I just did a quick check and it worked.

Comment: i'll try it asap